# How to get the PullRequest Modified file count and line count in bitbucket Rest api

Tags: bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

From bitbucket Rest api how can I get the PullRequst modified line count and file count. I used this "https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/{userName}/{repoName}/pullrequests/2/diff". But this return as file.can I get the filecount and line count from rest api itself?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the endpoint `diffstat`, which also give you stats lines added/deleted per file. So, you still would need to sum up over all files.

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D/diffstat